# Trying to Append Retweeted Tweet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, nsstring

I am trying to append the string of a Retweeted tweet in Objective-C however I am always getting an issue with certain types of tweets. I believe that there is something wrong in the way I am attempting to substring the tweets. My code is shown below

```
  2015-08-20 15:40:20.699 Floadt[21417:932559] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {9223372036854775807, 52} out of bounds; string length 70'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd58c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c631bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd58b9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc7fb98 -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:] + 136
    4   Floadt                              0x000000010929efa4 -[TwitterTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 2260
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b465a28 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b444248 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2853
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b45a8a9 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 210
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b3e4a2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    9   QuartzCore                          0x000000010b1a6ec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b19b6d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b19b546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b107886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b108a3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010b1090eb _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc8bca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc8bc00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc81a33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc81366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010eb09a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010b364900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    21  Floadt                              0x000000010936574f main + 111
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f32f145 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is my code to Append the string:

```
if ([self Contains:@"RT" on:[data objectForKey:@"text"]]) {
    TwitterRetweetCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TwitterRetweetCell"];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TwitterRetweetCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TwitterRetweetCell"];
    }
    // Lookup RT User
    NSString *text = [data objectForKey:@"text"];

    NSRange start = [text rangeOfString:@"RT @"];
    NSRange end = [text rangeOfString:@":"];
    NSString *shortString = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location, end.location)];
    NSString *evenShorterString = [shortString substringFromIndex:4];

    [self lookupTwitterUser:evenShorterString];

    //Set username for twitter
    [cell.nameLabel setText:evenShorterString];

    //Set Retweet Status
    NSString *retName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Retweeted by %@",data[@"user"][@"screen_name"]];
    [cell.retweetedLabel setText:retName];


    //Set Profile Pic for Twitter
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ranges:

```
    NSRange start = [text rangeOfString:@"RT @"];
    NSRange end = [text rangeOfString:@":"];
```

You need to check that those substrings were actually found and only use the ranges if they were found. Otherwise the rest of your code will fail because the range's location will be NSNotFound, which is the large number in your crash log. That suggests that your code encountered text containing "RT" but not "RT @". You should perform the following check before attempting to use start and end:

```
if (start.location != NSNotFound && end.location != NSNotFound)
{
    // use start and end
}
```

Or better still, use this if condition instead of `if ([self Contains:@"RT" on:[data objectForKey:@"text"]])`.